# Create unique dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, loops

For each city (here : NY, Chicago) I have 3 csv files with 2 columns like this :

file 1 : ID, 20101201

file 2 : ID, 20101202

file 3 : ID, 20101203

Each file name is like this : "Chicago_*ID*_20101201.csv"

The 2nd column name is representing a date in this format YYYYMMDD.

I want to create a unique file for each city with a dataframe containing 4 columns: ID and the 3 other columns referring to each date in these files.

```
cities = ["NY","Chicago"]
dates = ["20101201", "20101202","20101203"]

for city in cities:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for date in dates:

        file_name = f'{city}_ID_{date}.csv' 

        df[date] = pd.read_csv('[...]')

        print(df[date])
```

Plus i would like to know if there is a way to avoid giving the list of dates in the case that i would want to do it for an entire month.

Thanks

Comment: All files have the same number of rows?

Comment: Not necessarily

Comment: So how do you align rows? By `'ID'` value?

Comment: @Corralien yes it is my key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pathlib`:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib
import collections

# the path to your csv files
DATA_DIR = pathlib.Path("cities")
cities = collections.defaultdict(list)

# Collect data
for file in DATA_DIR.glob('*_ID_*.csv'):
    city = file.stem.split('_')[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype=object).drop_duplicates('ID')
    cities[city].append(df.set_index('ID'))

# Build city files
for city in cities:
    df = pd.concat(cities[city], axis=1).reset_index()
    df.to_excel(DATA_DIR / f'{city}.xlsx', index=False)
```

Now you have two files Chicago.xlsx and NY.xlsx.

Comment: Got this error : SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
This is what i've put in DATA_DIR path : "'C:\\Users\\dvs\\Documents\\96. Files"

Comment: No error now but it seems that nothing has been created after running the code

Comment: Nothing in the output

Comment: Fixed it but i have an other error : "pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" at the "df = pd.concat(....)" line

Comment: OK. you have multiple same ID in one file?

Comment: Yes there are duplicates

Comment: So what do you want to do when in first file there are 2 ID '123' and second file only 1 ID '123'?

Comment: I want to remove duplicates because for each ID the value of the column YYYYMMDD is the same in each file. Hope it's clear

Comment: I slightly modified my answer to drop duplicates on same file. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 1):

You can read each dataframe, store them in a list, set the ID as index and concatenate them to get one ID column and three other date columns:

```
cities = ["NY","Chicago"]
dates = ["20101201", "20101202","20101203"]

for city in cities:
    df_list=[]
    for date in dates:
        file_name = f'{city}_ID_{date}.csv' 
        df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file_name, index_col='ID'))
    df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
    print(f'This is the dataframe for {city}', df)
```

For your second question, you can create any date range, using pandas daterange:

```
pd.date_range(start="20101101", end="20101201", freq='D').strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Output:

```
Index(['20101101', '20101102', '20101103', '20101104', '20101105', '20101106',
       '20101107', '20101108', '20101109', '20101110', '20101111', '20101112',
       '20101113', '20101114', '20101115', '20101116', '20101117', '20101118',
       '20101119', '20101120', '20101121', '20101122', '20101123', '20101124',
       '20101125', '20101126', '20101127', '20101128', '20101129', '20101130',
       '20101201'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: hi, got this error : ValueError: Missing column provided to 'parse_dates': '20101201'

Comment: Hello. I edited my answer. Let me know if it still gives you an error.

Comment: Now i got this error : pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 3